# Sails JS - Access model in view script tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I ve got a view called `vertrag.ejs` in `views/entrance/`.

It gets its data to show from the controller `view-vertrag.js` in `api/controllers/entrance/` in this way :

```
var dcrm = await 
Crm.find({where: {vertrag: tk}});
```

Crm is the Model.

In the view, it is possible to change every property and save it with a button next to it. Of course this data should go back to the database.

But I don't get the data not until the view is loaded of course. So Im now in a script tag at the end of `vertrag.ejs` and want to call `sails.sendNativeQuery()`.

There is the keyword sails not referenced because its client side JS.

Now I dont know what to do.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Or in other words: Is it possible to call a function in controller from view?

Answer (score 0):

@kandre Try making an API that updates the data of your particular model in database. This way you can work asynchronously without reloading the page in order to work. It's a way around.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).